# Abort thread with openmp parallelization

Tags: c++, winforms, thread-safety, openmp

I have encountered a strange yet understandable error solution to which I cannot figure out on my own. I am creating thread `System::Threading::Thread` to run function like this :

```
try
{
   perform_adapt_rgb(alg);
   Control::Invoke(adpt_deg2);
}
   catch ( ThreadAbortException^ e ) 
{
   Control::Invoke(adpt_deg2);
   //Thread::ResetAbort();
}
```

I am not pasting whole thing since it does not make sense to make it complicated. Invoke updates my UI.. Problem arises when void perform_adapt_rgb(int alg); function encapsulate OMP for cycles and I try to kill the process from UI by thread->Abort(); function. While testing inside visual studio everything works fine but if executed from exe file, it shows application not responding -> wait for solution, close dialog. Now my guess is that forcing OMP-ed for cycle to end unexpectedly is what is causing the problem, however i am not entirely sure since it does work in VS where i can debug it. Everything works fine without OMP. Could somebody point me to a workaround on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I sorted it out. It is probably not the best solution but it works so it doesn't matter to me anymore. What I do now is breaking long OMP for cycles into parts a check some global bool to find out if i need to break out of the function. Than i simply perform thread suicide ... Call abort from inside the tread at the end o f evaluation rather that abort it from UI. I am keeping it open in case sb have a better solution.